# Remove the border of a table headerCell itext7 pdf

Tags: pdf, javafx, itext, cell, itext7

I am creating a table using itext7.

I can change the color of a regular cell. How can I change the border to Null of a header cell?

I cannot add a check to create a "false" headerCell as the table may be a mutli-column so I would like the cells to be atop each column.

Having this false headerCell would just be on the first cell generated.

I tried:

```
            //does not work.
            table.setBorder(null);

            //---------------------------does not work.
            table.addHeaderCell("one: ").setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            table.addHeaderCell("two: ").setBorder(null).addStyle(normal);
            table.addHeaderCell("three: ").setBorder(null).addStyle(normal);
```

Minimal:(just set your location)
    package application;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.Color;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocumentInfo;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfString;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfViewerPreferences;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.ColumnDocumentRenderer;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Style;
import com.itextpdf.layout.border.Border;
import com.itextpdf.layout.border.SolidBorder;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        exportRes();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }



    public void exportRes() throws IOException{             
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(--location--);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);


        pdf.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
        pdf.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));

        PdfDocumentInfo info = pdf.getDocumentInfo();
        info.setTitle("List");

        Document document = new Document(pdf,PageSize.A4);

        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA); 


        Style normal = new Style();
        normal.setFont(font).setFontSize((float) 7.5);

        Style notesF = new Style();
        notesF.setFont(font).setItalic().setFontSize((float) 7.5);

        Style lastNameF = new Style();
        lastNameF.setFont(font).setFontSize((float) 7.5).setBold();


        Table table = new Table(new float[]{(float) 2,29,10});
        table.setWidthPercent(100);
        table.setFont(font);


        //does not work.
        table.setBorder(null);

        //---------------------------does not work.
        table.addHeaderCell("one: ").setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
        table.addHeaderCell("two: ").setBorder(null).addStyle(normal);
        table.addHeaderCell("three: ").setBorder(null).addStyle(normal);


        Cell check = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(" ").addStyle(normal).setFixedLeading(0)).setBorder(new SolidBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, (float) 0.5));
        table.addCell(check);

        Text lastName = new Text("Name ").setBold().addStyle(lastNameF);

        Text address = new Text("address").addStyle(normal);

        Cell name = new Cell().add(new Paragraph().add(lastName).add(address)).setBorder(new SolidBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, (float) 0.5));
        table.addCell(name);


        Cell notes = new Cell().add("notes").addStyle(notesF).setBorder(new SolidBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, (float) 0.5));
        table.addCell(notes);


        document.add(table);
        document.close();

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost right. The problem is very simple and can be found in the next line:

```
table.addHeaderCell("one: ").setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
```

Notice that Table#addHeaderCell method returns Table **not Cell** object. So then you apply `Border.NO_BORDER` on Table.

The solution is:

```
table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add("one: ").setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
```

Also if you want to set specific border on header/footer (the analog of Table border), write summat `table.getHeader().setBorder(your border)`. Notice also that itext applys table border on header/footer too.

I also want to mention that invoking Table constructor as you do isn't 100% correct if you use itext 7.0.2+. If you want columns widths to be in a ratio 2 29 30 (or any else), call `Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{2, 29, 30)) ;`